# Migration of browser tokens

Tags: push-notification

I want to move the Browser tokens I have collected from one vendor to another. It seems when I am trying to move it, the other vendor says that tokens would be lost.

Does anyone know how can we do it in simple steps ?

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: I am collecting Browser tokens using Browser Push Notification since last 1 year using a 3rd party application. Now I want to move to a different 3rd party application and I don’t have an idea how to migrate my existing Browser tokens to the new 3rd party application.